# How do I find the number of times a word has been repeated in a tweepy stream?

Tags: python, stream, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I've recently been working with the tweepy library in python. I wrote a program that streams through tweets. I've used strings as filters. 
I've assigned a certain variable to each string in a list depending on the mood the string represents.

```
    class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        try:
            print status
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed on status, ', str(e)
            time.sleep(5)
            if '' in status.text.lower() and 'retweeted_status' not in status:
                print status.text
                print status.coordinates

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())

api = tweepy.API(auth)


happy=["I love","I'm so happy","feeling joyful","feeling awesome"]
sad=["I'm depressed","I'm very sad","It is painful","feeling terible"]
angry=["I'm furious","wtf!","I'm so pissed off","I'm angry"]
shocked=["rip","omg","I can't believe it","I'm shocked"]
romantic=["I love you","today is my anniversary","feeling romantic","I'm dating"]

twitterStream.filter(track=sad)(track=happy)(track=angry)(track=shocked)(track=romantic)

mood_happy=0
mood_sad=0
mood_angry=0
mood_shocked=0
mood_romantic=0
```

What I wanted to do was each time the string from any variable appears in the line of tweets I wanted the value of mood_n to add up to 1. So for example if the phrase 'Feeling Joyful' appears 5 times in the stream. I would want the value of mood_happy=5. How can I go about this?

I'm sorry, I'm aware that i'm not supposed to post such queries but I've been searching for the solution on google from many hours but haven't found a single bit of information on this. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a place for optimizations, but basically it looks like:

```
import time
from tweepy import StreamListener, OAuthHandler, Stream


twitter_access = {
    "consumer_key"       : "enter_consumer_key",
    "consumer_secret"    : "enter_consumer_secret",
    "access_token"       : "enter_access_token",
    "access_token_secret": "enter_access_token_secret",
}

happy = ["I love", "I'm so happy", "feeling joyful", "feeling awesome"]
sad = ["I'm depressed", "I'm very sad", "It is painful", "feeling terible"]
angry = ["I'm furious", "wtf!", "I'm so pissed off", "I'm angry"]
shocked = ["rip", "omg", "I can't believe it", "I'm shocked"]
romantic = ["I love you", "today is my anniversary", "feeling romantic", "I'm dating"]

mood_happy = 0
mood_sad = 0
mood_angry = 0
mood_shocked = 0
mood_romantic = 0


class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        global mood_happy, mood_sad, mood_angry, mood_shocked, mood_romantic

        try:
            # print status
            tweet_text = status.text
            for mood_n_score in [[happy, 'mood_happy'], [sad, 'mood_sad'], [angry, 'mood_angry'],
                                 [shocked, 'mood_shocked'], [romantic, 'mood_romantic']]:
                lst_mood = mood_n_score[0]
                type_mood = mood_n_score[1]

                for mood in lst_mood:
                    if mood in tweet_text:
                        if type_mood == 'mood_happy':
                            mood_happy += 1
                        elif type_mood == 'mood_sad':
                            mood_sad += 1
                        elif type_mood == 'mood_angry':
                            mood_angry += 1
                        elif type_mood == 'mood_shocked':
                            mood_shocked += 1
                        else:
                            mood_romantic += 1
                        break

            print('\n----------------')
            print 'mood_happy:', mood_happy
            print 'mood_sad:', mood_sad
            print 'mood_angry:', mood_angry
            print 'mood_shocked:', mood_shocked
            print 'mood_romantic:', mood_romantic

            # return True

        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed on status, ', str(e)
            time.sleep(5)
            if '' in status.text.lower() and 'retweeted_status' not in status:
                print status.text
                print status.coordinates

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status

auth = OAuthHandler(twitter_access["consumer_key"], twitter_access["consumer_secret"])
auth.set_access_token(twitter_access["access_token"], twitter_access["access_token_secret"])
# api = API(auth)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, Listener(), timeout=None)

for list_of_mood in [happy, sad, angry, shocked, romantic]:
    twitterStream.filter(track=list_of_mood)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was really helpful :)

Comment: @AmanTrivedi, I would appreciate if you could accept the answer (under the 2 up\down arrows in front of my answer there is a grey check mark). Thank you.

Comment: @TitantFighter Done :)

Comment: I had another question actually. If I use the code `Main_mood=max(mood_happy,mood_sad,mood_angry,mood_shocked,mood_romantic)`  and then only ask it to `print Main_mood`               would it work? Sorry I'm currently out, hence can't test the code at the moment.

Comment: @AmanTrivedi, if you mean to add this code under 6 print's (before `# return True`), than yes, it would work